# gvim how to change exisitng colorscheme's syntax colors?

Tags: vim, gvim, syntax-highlighting, color-theme

I use gvim and the color scheme which I use is called 'slate'. I mostly just code in python, html and css and I like slate's syntax coloring except for a few syntax colors. Is it possible for me to change a few of the syntax colors? For example, it colors all html tags blue, is it possible if I can change it to, say, red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two abstractions for syntax coloring in Vim. First, the *syntax plugin* provides definitions for the various syntax elements (e.g. an HTML tag name -> `htmlTagName`), and links them to generic *highlight groups* (e.g. `Statement`). A *colorscheme* then provides the actual attributes and colors for those (which can depend on whether you use GVIM or a terminal).

If you don't like the color / formatting of a particular highlight group, you'd basically create your own customized fork of the colorscheme. Copy the existing `colors/schemename.vim` to `~/.vim/colors/newscheme.vim`, and use the new name in your `.vimrc` via the `:colorscheme newscheme` command.

On the other hand, if you're fine with the general colors, and just think that a particular syntax element should use a different group, you can override the default assignment. In this example:

```
:syntax link htmlTagName Constant
```

Comment: Do you know whether there is a way to modify an existing colorscheme without copying the whole original file? I currently use slate, and I just don't like the white background for `PreProc`.

Comment: @steffen You can tweak a colorscheme with individual `:hi` commands _after_ the `:color` command (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`). E.g. `color slate` followed by `hi PreProc guibg=NONE`.

Comment: @steffen Alternatively (for cleaner separation / larger changes, or if you dynamically change colorschemes during Vim use), you can write a wrapper scheme (in `~/.vim/colors/myslate.vim`), where you `:runtime colors/slate.vim` and then append the `:hi` commands.

Answer (score 1):

gvim has files (eg. slate.vim) in a colors directory wherever it is installed. Where that is OS dependent. You could change them in there and it will change for all users.

You can override by putting a colors file (on Linux) in .vim/colors in your home directory. Not sure what to call the directory in windows. This looks like a pretty comprehensive tutorial: http://andrewradev.com/2011/08/06/making-vim-pretty-with-custom-colors/